# Can I get the total count of a post likes, shares and comments using facebook sdk in Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the total number of counts of a facebook post in python. The code below is giving a json object of some persons who likes the post. But not all. I need total counts. Is it possible?

```
import requests
import facebook
token=''
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
lik = graph.get_connections(id='10153608167431961', connection_name='likes')
print(lik)
```

Result is :

> {'data': [{'id': '1583767538554134', 'name': 'Øp Pö'}, {'id': '120568968399628', 'name': 'William Anthony Christo'}, {'id': '699615593474341', 'name': 'Anum Rabani'}, {'id': '290360191169562', 'name': 'রফিকুল ইসলাম তৌফিক'}, {'id': '119195851825867', 'name': 'Anant Gharte'}, {'id': '1584033738513309', 'name': 'Miguel Gates'}, {'id': '170725429957788', 'name': 'Rahmatullah Kazimi'}, {'id': '165244040549022', 'name': 'Jose Marques'}, {'id': '553277864818751', 'name': 'Shubham Kumar'}, {'id': '177910112626556', 'name': 'Rajesh Singh'}, {'id': '10206027408500948', 'name': 'Cüneyt Ekin'}, {'id': '134409193615843', 'name': 'Moazzem Hossain'}, {'id': '1452911201684073', 'name': 'Sohail Noori'}, {'id': '706685776074740', 'name': 'Man Muet'}, {'id': '1655289584790642', 'name': 'Emeghara Lucky Kelechi'}, {'id': '10205877189481867', 'name': 'Danielle Oliver Solomon'}, {'id': '511315079054021', 'name': 'Ajay Kumar'}, {'id': '659773750764822', 'name': 'Tiago Balloni'}, {'id': '385284718315460', 'name': 'Ivica Herman'}, {'id': '394871897335035', 'name': 'Zubayer Hassan'}, {'id': '532960883548514', 'name': 'Mohan Rathod'}, {'id': '373452456160618', 'name': 'Jeevajohthy Pramulu Naidu'}, {'id': '803092719700936', 'name': 'Patricia Ann Harris'}, {'id': '960692997327631', 'name': 'Osama Ozy'}, {'id': '739963022766566', 'name': 'Abdalrhman Selim'}], 'paging': {'next': 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/10153608167431961/likes?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAJZC5cI5OJZC6l6XZATLGsBjutHdQyvqEs4yQk7HejvKNAHqLwdNgANtMdvnGAekUo7Mx10u8K2MydmOCNNzEDmPAL3kTQITKTYIwwD1ZCNTjpLtSnZATTiW0xWrnaFbjJomXKQUnkMpF3ZCBqh6WYMixkh5tuhQZDZD&limit=25&after=NzM5OTYzMDIyNzY2NTY2', 'cursors': {'before': 'MTU4Mzc2NzUzODU1NDEzNAZDZD', 'after': 'NzM5OTYzMDIyNzY2NTY2'}}}

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/object/likes ?

Comment: @MooingRawr For getting shared posts counts https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/object/sharedposts/ is telling `sharedposts` is the right edge but it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this API call:

```
/10153608167431961?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)
```

Result:

```
{
  "likes": {
    "data": [
    ],
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 13260,
      "can_like": true,
      "has_liked": false
    }
  },
  "id": "10153608167431961"
}
```

Alternative:

```
/10153608167431961/likes?summary=true&limit=0
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 13260,
    "can_like": true,
    "has_liked": false
  }
}
```

The same for comments:

```
/10153608167431961/comments?summary=true&limit=0
```

I am not sure why it does not work with `/sharedposts`, it may be a bug, it may be intentional for some reason.

Comment: Can I also get comments and shares counts using this call?

Comment: I replaced likes by shares but it is not working. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/object/sharedposts/ is telling `sharedposts` but why not working? :(

Comment: "it may be a bug, it may be intentional for some reason." - you can file a bug if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty late, but you can use the insights metric `post_story_adds_by_action_type`, which will give you a breakdown of comments, likes, and shares.

Try this:

```
/{object-id}/insights/post_story_adds_by_action_type
```

Which should yield something like:

```
{'description': 'Lifetime: The number of unique people who created a story about your Page post by interacting with it. (Unique Users)',
   'id': {object-d}/insights/post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique/lifetime',
   'name': 'post_story_adds_by_action_type_unique',
   'period': 'lifetime',
   'title': 'Lifetime Talking About This (Post) by action type',
   'values': [{'value': {'comment': 10, 'like': 20, 'share': 30}}]}]}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/insights

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17761134)

Comment: Good point, sorry I'm new! I'll add some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

graph.get_connections(id='10153608167431961', connection_name='likes', summary='true')

This should give the total likes for the given post/feed.